# "DataFrame object has no attribute dt" error

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe with some dates (datetime64[ns]):

```
            A6U20      A6Z20      A6H21      A6M21      A6U21      A6Z21
expiry 2020-09-14 2020-12-14 2021-03-15 2021-06-14 2021-09-13 2021-12-13
```

I want to create another dataframe with the number of days between each column and the preceding one.
I tried the following:

```
df2 = (df - df.shift(axis=1))
```

which resulted in:

```
       A6U20   A6Z20   A6H21   A6M21   A6U21   A6Z21
expiry   NaT 91 days 91 days 91 days 91 days 91 days
```

which is fine, except that I don't need the "days" suffix at the end of each timedelta value.
After reading some similar questions, I tried the following command:

```
df2 = (df - df.shift(axis=1)).dt.days
```

which resulted in the following error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dt'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) attribute is for objects of type Series, not DataFrame.

If you just want the number of days instead of a pandas.Timedelta object, you can do this:

```py
df2 = (df - df.shift(axis=1))
df2.loc['expiry',:] = df2.loc['expiry',:].dt.days
```

Output:

```
       A6U20 A6Z20 A6H21 A6M21 A6U21 A6Z21
expiry   NaT  91.0  91.0  91.0  91.0  91.0
```

If you would like the `NaT` to be replaced with `0` days, you can use `fillna()`:

```py
df2 = (df - df.shift(axis=1)).fillna(pd.Timedelta(0))
df2.loc['expiry',:] = df2.loc['expiry',:].dt.days
```

Output:

```
       A6U20 A6Z20 A6H21 A6M21 A6U21 A6Z21
expiry     0    91    91    91    91    91
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out dt works only on series and not on dataframes.
The following apply function did the trick:

```
df2 = df2.apply(lambda x : x.dt.days)
```